# Fantasy about a girl transforming to a dragon, titled something like "Rigals daughter"

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a short story called "Rigals daughter" (or something similar) about a girl who transforms into a dragon when she touches the throne with a scepter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"**[Daughter of Regals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daughter_of_Regals)**" by Stephen R Donaldson. It's in the short story collection of the same name.

[image: Cover of *Daughter of Regals*]

The plot is pretty much as you described.

> It tells of a young woman called Chrysalis, the nominal ruler of three kingdoms who is about to come of age. To claim her throne, Chrysalis must exhibit the magical abilities of her ancestors the Regals - who combined the attributes of human men and mythical creatures - or else her dominions will collapse into civil war. While the kings of the individual kingdoms plot against her, Chrysalis struggles to release the magic inherent within her and claim her inheritance.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I remember this being a fascinating story; I am going to try to buy it online right now! Appreciate your help :)